# Explicitly passing an vector of shared_ptr into a function

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `Base` and a number of `Derived` classes that all define a common method `foo`. `foo` is defined with a definition in Base class and is virtual. `Derived` objects can call `Base::foo()` in their own `foo` methods if they wish. Each `Derived` class has its own set of constructor parameters different from that of the `Base` class.

I know the terminology is funky but when I say each Derived class I mean there are class definitions like `class Parrot: public Base` and `class Dog: public Base`.

I have the following method

```
void addImportantObjects(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> objects);
```

That will eventually save each of those shared pointers to various internal vectors so it can iterate through them and call `foo` and have the proper `foo` of the `Derived` class called.

I am going to be calling this method frequently and I want to get it as small/functional looking and easy to read as possible. Obviously it would be nice to hide away the construction of the vector or the pointer casts if possible.

This is the best I have been able to do thus far

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> objs;
objs.push_back(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(std::make_shared<Derived>(args)));
objs.push_back(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(std::make_shared<Derived2>(args)));
addImportantObjects(objs);
```

You can see a lot of space is wasted with the casting and the push_backs and the shared pointer syntax. If I had a long list of objects I wished to add it would be be a lot of code.

My question is there any way I could make it look more closer to perhaps

```
addImportantObjects({Derived(args), Derived2(args)})
```

In case it is important here these objects will not be referenced outside of the scope of the object with the addImportantObjects method. The shared pointer is just to ensure that internally it does not copy anything as it processes it. Any method that allows this to happen but does not  copy the object more than once would be ok.

Comment: Remove the casts, they don't do anything useful. The syntax will be much more concise then.

Comment: For up-casting you do not need any explicit call to `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Comment: you are over thinking, this should all just work, no fancy casting needed

Comment: `addImportantObjects({std::make_shared<Derived>(args), std::make_shared<Derived2>(args)});` works.

Comment: I dont know how I didnt notice. That I thought I tried that earlier.